# Paths in Lua: Unable to run script in Windows for Lua that requires 'wx'

Tags: lua

I am using Lua for Windows.

I am trying a sample script from the wxLua website; however, when I run the script, it fails on the first line, which is `require 'wx'` with:

```
lua: cannot open wx: No such file or directory
```

However, when executing `require 'wx'` in the REPL/interpreter, it works OK.

I have done another script to output `print(package.cpath)` and `print(package.path)`, and they seem the same to me as in the REPL.

Why, when running the script, is it not able to find 'wx'?

**In this instance, I am running both the script and the shell/REPL from the same folder.**

The value of package.cpath (produced by test script and Lua shell):

```
.\?.dll;.\?51.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lu a\5.1\?51.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\ Lua\5.1\clibs\?51.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll;C:\Program File s (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll
```

and package.path (again, the same from the script and Lua shell):

```
;.\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?\init.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\?\init.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac
```

There is a `wx.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs` which is referenced by the cpath value above.

Comment: Are you running the script and interpreter from the same working directory? Just for completness, can you add what `package.path` and `package.cpath` is? The latter is more relevant since `wx` is a Lua C extension.

Comment: Thanks @greatwolf, I have followed your advice and added the relevant detail.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your setup. Does running an empty script containing just `require 'wx'` still give that error?

Comment: Yes, it gives `lua: .\wx.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'wx'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\wx.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        wx2.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?` which is rather weird.

Comment: Am I missing some other initialization?

Comment: Never mind. I got it. I named the script wx.lua, which is a bad move to begin with :-) Renaming it solved it.

Comment: lol, that wasn't very smart.

Comment: Funny, I've done the same thing at least once before in another scripting language as well. Hm.

Comment: Would you suggest closing this question or adding the solution as an answer? You never know if someone else might benefit from it... (But sometimes the community gets very funny about such Q&As)

Comment: I think adding a solution would be appropriate. So it won't show up on SO as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this was my own stupidity: I named the file `wx.lua`, so obviously `require` was trying to pick up the script itself.

By simply renaming the file, it works fine.